# Multiple Possible RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It is very possible that a given controller method may get called by several other controller methods in an application. When that happens, the given method needs to have a way to determine where to Redirect back when done. What is the appropriate way to inform the method which one of the possible Redirect choices to execute. I suppose one way to deal with this might be to pass that information into the method at time of execution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Request Uri?